# How to create a self closing element in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I want to create a custom self closing node in CKeditor, is there a way to do this?
My code so far:

```
this.videoElement = editor.document.createElement('cfwvideo');
this.videoElement.setAttribute('src', videoSource);
editor.insertElement(this.videoElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah found it, you'll have to add the control name to the $empty list in CKEDITOR.dtd like this: `CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty['cfwvideo'] = 1;`